# ssh script cannot access internet

Tags: bash, ssh, proxy

i have 2 server A and B
both are behind proxies and can access internet

i have a file test.py in server B

```
import os
os.system ("wget google.com")
```

now i try to ssh into B from A using following command

```
ssh B python test.py
```

however the script cannot access internet...connection to google.com failed.

if i personally ssh into the server B and do the same command it works...
Why doesnot it work through the bash script?

Comment: Your test.py is not valid python. Please use copy-paste to ensure the posted code is what you actually run.

Comment: Do you have to set any environment variables to make `wget` work? Like a proxy server for example?

Answer (score 1):

The Proxy was not getting set up. So I have to export all my proxy command through that python file